# Get total row count of an csv file with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have .csv files that are updated periodically and I need to output the total row count in an .html file.

I'm not that bad when it comes to jQuery, but this I never did and really would use some help form someone that has any experience with this.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript client framework, meaning it is supposed to manipulate html. You have csv files, are they loaded into your page, in html ? Otherwise jQuery is of no use here. You will need to do the counting at the server side (assuming the server is the one who loads/processes the csv files).

Comment: Well I'm aware of jQuery's nature, but was hoping that there is some method that will allow me to get file content.

Comment: so you need to load a csv into html ? and want to do it with jQuery ?

Comment: Instead of telling the OP what to do, just answer already. If you dont know the answer, dont say anything.

Answer (score 4):

1. Read the csv file

   var csvContents = getCsvContents(myFile);
2. Split the lines

   var lines = csvContents.split('\n');
3. Get the count

   lines.length

Example:

```
 var myFileUri = "file.csv";
 alertCsvCount(myFileUri);

 function alertCsvCount(myFile){
   //use jquery get
   $.get(myFile, function(data) {
      var lineCount = data.split('\n').length;
      //do what you want to do in lineCount
      alert(lineCount);
   })
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for, but getCsvContents(myFile) isn't an actual thing... at least not for jQuery.

Comment: I know but you have $.get(csvFile, funcition... and csvFile is not defined.

Comment: for the record, Javascript is not Java

Comment: Stil myFile and myFileUri need to be the same to get it to work, thanks for your help bro!

Also my bad, was in a hurry and I've put Java insted of Javascript.

Comment: @Dino remember to accept this answer if it was useful for you.